# Android studio, making a math formula sheet application

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, imageview, zooming

So I am still quiet the novice when it comes to programming but I was curious as to what would be the best practice to making a formula sheet. Of course it'll be just straight words, letters and numbers in the layout but some of those math formulas have a lot of characters that wouldn't be able to be read by the textview. So should I just make screenshots of formulas I make on word or is that too much memory to waste. Also to zoom in and out how do I go about that.

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML code in string.xml file in value folder.

```
<string name="superscript"><html><i>a</i><sup>2</sup>+<i>y</i><sup>2</sup></html></string>
<string name="subscript"><html>f(x)<sub>1+x</sub></html></string>
```

And in xml layout

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/superscript" />

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/subscript" />
```

Links for mathematical symbols and characters:

http://barzilai.org/math_sym.htm

http://www.myphysicslab.com/web_math.html

Comment: Thanks, but wouldnt this be very tedious.

Comment: Adding HTML will be a lot of work i know. But adding Textview will be more or less copy/paste thing. Taking screenshot or writing in textview is also a lot of work. So doing a little more work for a better view of your app is not bad i think :) @user4914918

Answer (score 0):

That is true its all about the appearance. But what if I'm trying to make a table like the Laplace table, would it be better to have an image

Comment: Remember when you use image you dont have any control over the font sizes etc anymore. And dont forget about the memory space it will consume

Comment: So its best to still do the method above

Comment: I can't seem to write the quadratic equation as a stacked fraction with a horizontal line in it

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable using webview in android, then of course! you can use javascript library **jqMath** to showcase any number of mathematical equations on a web page.
https://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html